# PHP Smarty dynamically insert an include into a Smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

The system I'm working with gets a string of HTML from a database and passes it down to smarty like so:

```
$smarty->assign('content', $content);
$smarty->display($template);
```

So nothing fancy. They now want to add dynamic includes which will include a component based on a string that they add via the WYSIWYG. For example:

```
[[latest-slider]]
```

Would translate to

```
{include file='components/latest-slider.tpl'}
```

The string replace is no problem as I just regex over the text and replace it appropriately. Now when it comes to displaying the output Smarty simply sees this as a string, it doesn't notice the fact it's smarty code and doesn't parse it.

I tried getting the complied template with Smarty `fetch()` and then do the regex replace and `eval()` on it. However, this is not a path I can go down as it fails to parse it because it no longer sees any of the `{literally}` tags. The main one being around the Google Analytics code and falls over `Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like the following

PHP:

```
$component = preg_replace(/some regex/, 'replacement', $content);
$smarty->assign('component', 'components/'.$component.'.tpl');

$smarty->assign('content', $content);
$smarty->display($template);
```

TPL `$template`:

```
{include file=$component}
```

Comment: The potential problem I see with this is assigning the include in the correct place on the page? How will it know to insert the include instead of the string `[[latest-slider]]` as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Better way is use smarty filter output.

```
$smarty->registerFilter("pre", 'myFunc');

function myFunc($tpl_output)
{
   $tpl_output = str_replace('[[latest-slider]]', '{include file='components/latest-slider.tpl'}', $tpl_output);

   //or regex: $tpl_output = preg_replace('/some regex/', 'replace', $tpl_output);
   return $tpl_output;
}
```

This will replace [[latest-slider]] **before** page is fetch for smarty render.

Comment: Hi r_a_f, I like this idea and have it working but it's still giving me the same result as what I tried in my question. All it's doing is printing out the include as a string, it isn't including it as expected.

Comment: PRE! not OUTPUT:  `$smarty->registerFilter("pre", 'myFunc');`  (I correct an answer)